# "Missing Parameter Values" exception only on 64bits executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, 32bit-64bit

I have an application written in C# (Visual Studio 2010) that is using Crystal Reports (13.0.2000.0)

When I compile the code for x86 platform everything works fine. The same code compiled for 64bits fails on Export() to PDF.

I'm assigning parameters in the following way:

ListReport.AddParameter("p_UserObjectID", objectId.ToString());

ListReport.ApplyParameters();

The libs I'm using:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine (13.0.2000.0)
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource (13.0.2000.0)
CrystalDecisions.Shared (13.0.2000.0)
```

StackTrace:

```
<CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldCurrentValueException>

  <Message>Missing parameter values.</Message>

  <StackTrace>
    <Frame>CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)</Frame>

    <Frame>CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)</Frame>

    <Frame>CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)</Frame>

    <Frame>CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)</Frame>

    <Frame>CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export(ExportOptions options)</Frame>

    <Frame>Fsm.Business.BLReport.CRWFunctions.CRWExport(ReportDocument CRWRpt, CrwExportOptions crwExportOpt, String filename)</Frame>

  </StackTrace>

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException>

    <Message>Missing parameter values.</Message>

    <StackTrace>

      <Frame>CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)</Frame>

      <Frame>CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)</Frame>

    </StackTrace>

  </System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException>

</CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldCurrentValueException>
```

Any ideas/clues/hints what could I miss?

Comment: This sounds like a CR bug.  Contact SAP for support.

Answer (score 0):

The report has parameters for which the values should be provided.

The code fails at export because the report could not populte the parameter values.

Pulled from here: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3228829